# Show/Hide Markers on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, show-hide, togglebutton, markers

I've seen the same question asked before but they all seemed specific to their situation and I didn't really understand as I am new to JS.

I have a google map api already rendered. I have created 3 separate arrays, each with a long list of locations for google map markers. All the markers are currently showing on the map.

I have created 3 separate buttons and I would like each button to show/hide the markers in it's corresponding array.

I really appreciate any help given, I have been searching for a week on how to do it and am sure its fairly simple but being new I'm just not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

when you create marker an object is returned, store this array of markers on a global var.
In the event of the button0 markers[0].setMap(map);
In the event of the button1 markers[1].setMap(map);

Comment: source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove